# Inheritance hierarchy for number system classes

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

For symbolic representation of mathematical expressions, I am trying to build a hierarchy of number system classes.

In addition to `Integer` and `Real`, I also need classes like `Rational` and `Complex`. I want all of these classes to inter-operate seamlessly with each other.

e.g. Adding a `Complex` number to an `Integer` would give a `Complex` number etc.

---

I made all of them to implement the `Number` interface. (NOT `java.lang.Number`)

For being able to add numbers of different types, I tried making hierarchy like following.

> `Integer` extends `Rational` extends `Real` extends `Complex`

- This makes an `Integer` to unnecessarily store imaginary part etc. This overhead is undesired.
- Also allowing access to imaginary part of an `Integer` seems improper.

---

Can anyone suggest a better design where overhead is avoided and interoperation is still possible?

Comment: Why not use something like [Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) for this?

Comment: Not just unnecessarily store but also *allow access to imaginary part*

Comment: Commons math does not allow interoperation like I described above.

Comment: I would not make such hirerarchy at all, just implement common interface and perform operations over it. Making `Integer` extending `Real` is bad idea because real (which in common case is not rational) needs some special inner representation, so operations should be performed according to it.

Comment: @TheLostMind Thanks for input. Allowing access is also a bad idea. I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather create an interface that has something like getRealPart() and getImaginaryPart(). Then your integer can simply return 0 for getImaginaryPart(). That since you want Integer to "be" a Complex, but you don't want Integer to contain the internal implementation of Complex.

Comment: and what if real part is not rational? How should you return it?

Comment: Well the return type can be whatever. So I guess "Real" or something like that.

Comment: Common interface would require a single return type for integers, real numbers and rational numbers. The lack of such unified return type itself is the purpose of making this hierarchy.

Comment: @TanmayPatil you can define method that checks or returns "minimum type"

Comment: Single return type? Not sure what you mean (return type for a specific method?) or how you're planning to avoid it with extending a class instead of implementing an interface.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Adding numbers of different types should return number of "minimum type". Defining a method to return the minimum type is like admitting that it can not be implemented in the type system.

Comment: @MarcusWidegren I know that extending the class is the worst idea. I agree that the interface removes storage overhead. But what should I keep the return types of methods like plus for example?

Comment: @TanmayPatil no, operations (plus, minus, square etc) should be performed only on interface, "minimum type" method just for checking type and conversion.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Keeping return types of all operations as Complex would not be a great idea. How can I specify different return types according to combinations of operands using "minimum type method"? Thanks again.

Comment: @TanmayPatil Maybe simply method overloading? So in the interface every method is like "Complex add(Complex otherNumber)", and then in for example Real you can have "Complex add(Complex otherNumber)" but also "Real add(Real otherReal)". The compiler should then use the most specific overload it can, which should be what you want. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem here. Real number is a complex number, integer is a real number. Complex number can be expressed as `a + bi` and an integer is a complex number, such that `a` is an integer and `b = 0`. So every integer has `b` and it is equal to 0.

You may however consider using composition (and interfaces) over inheritance:

```
interface Complex {

    Real a();

    Real b();

}

interface Real extends Complex {

    @Override
    default Real b() {
        return new Integer(0);
    }

}

class Integer implements Real {

    public Integer(int value) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public Real a() {
        return this;
    }

    // ...

}
```

The disadvantage of this approach is that `Integer` class can override `b()` method, so maybe inheritance would be better, because you can use `final` keyword on the method:

```
abstract class Complex {

    abstract Real a();
    abstract Real b();

}

abstract class Real extends Complex {

    @Override
    public final Real b() {
        return new Integer(0);
    }

}

class Integer extends Real {

    public Integer(int value) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public Real a() {
        return this;
    }

    // ...

}
```

I have tried to model it myself and I came up with this terrible code below. I am not happy about it, because of the following problems:

- `Interface` - `InterfaceImpl` antipattern
- `IntegerNumber` has methods such as `realPart()` or `numerator()` and `denominator()`
- some numbers (complex and rational) use other numbers, while others (real and integer) use Java primitives

Code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ComplexNumber complexOne = new ComplexNumber(new RealNumber(1.25), new RealNumber(3));
        ComplexNumber complexTwo = new ComplexNumber(new RealNumber(7), new RealNumber(18.875));

        System.out.println("adding two complex numbers:");
        System.out.println(complexOne.add(complexTwo));


        RealNumber realOne = new RealNumber(15.125);
        RealNumber realTwo = new RealNumber(7.375);

        System.out.println("adding two real numbers:");
        System.out.println(realOne.add(realTwo));
        System.out.println(realTwo.add(realOne));

        System.out.println("adding complex and real number:");
        System.out.println(complexOne.add(realOne));
        System.out.println(realOne.add(complexOne));


        RationalNumber rationalOne = new RationalNumber(new IntegerNumber(1), new IntegerNumber(2));
        RationalNumber rationalTwo = new RationalNumber(new IntegerNumber(1), new IntegerNumber(3));

        System.out.println("adding two rational numbers:");
        System.out.println(rationalOne.add(rationalTwo));


        IntegerNumber integerOne = new IntegerNumber(6);
        IntegerNumber integerTwo = new IntegerNumber(7);

        System.out.println("adding two integers:");
        System.out.println(integerOne.add(integerTwo));

        System.out.println("adding real number and integer:");
        System.out.println(integerOne.add(realOne));
        System.out.println(realOne.add(integerOne));

        System.out.println("adding complex number and integer:");
        System.out.println(integerOne.add(complexOne));
        System.out.println(complexOne.add(integerOne));
    }

}

// interfaces

interface Complex {

    Real realPart();
    Real imaginaryPart();

    default Complex add(Complex other) {
        return new ComplexNumber(
                this.realPart().add(other.realPart()),
                this.imaginaryPart().add(other.imaginaryPart())
        );
    }

}

interface Real extends Complex {

    double asDouble();

    @Override
    default Real imaginaryPart() {
        return new IntegerNumber(0);
    }

    default Real add(Real other) {
        return new RealNumber(this.asDouble() + other.asDouble());
    }

}

interface Rational extends Real {

    Integer numerator();
    Integer denominator();

    @Override
    default Real realPart() {
        return new RealNumber(1.0d * numerator().asInt() / denominator().asInt());
    }

    @Override
    default double asDouble() {
        return realPart().asDouble();
    }

    default Rational add(Rational other) {
        return new RationalNumber(
                this.numerator().multiply(other.denominator()).add(this.denominator().multiply(other.numerator())),
                this.denominator().multiply(other.denominator())
        );
    }

}

interface Integer extends Rational {

    int asInt();

    @Override
    default Integer numerator() {
        return new IntegerNumber(asInt());
    }

    @Override
    default Integer denominator() {
        return new IntegerNumber(1);
    }

    default Integer add(Integer other) {
        return new IntegerNumber(this.asInt() + other.asInt());
    }

    default Integer multiply(Integer other) {
        return new IntegerNumber(this.asInt() * other.asInt());
    }

}

// implementations

class ComplexNumber implements Complex {

    private final Real realPart;
    private final Real imaginaryPart;

    public ComplexNumber(Real realPart, Real imaginaryPart) {
        this.realPart = realPart;
        this.imaginaryPart = imaginaryPart;
    }

    @Override
    public Real realPart() {
        return realPart;
    }

    @Override
    public Real imaginaryPart() {
        return imaginaryPart;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s + %si", realPart, imaginaryPart);
    }

}

class RealNumber implements Real {

    private final double value;

    public RealNumber(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public Real realPart() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public double asDouble() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + value;
    }

}

class RationalNumber implements Rational {

    private final Integer numerator;
    private final Integer denominator;

    public RationalNumber(Integer numerator, Integer denominator) {
        this.numerator = numerator;
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer numerator() {
        return numerator;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer denominator() {
        return denominator;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s/%s", numerator, denominator);
    }

}

class IntegerNumber implements Integer {

    private final int value;

    public IntegerNumber(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int asInt() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + value;
    }

}
```

I am wondering whether interfaces should be abstract classes with implemented methods being final. In the end, I think it may be better to just go with simple inheritance and ignore the fact that every integer will have a field for imaginary part.

I hope this will give you some ideas.

Comment: And what should return `a()` if number is non-rational (pi for example)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Could you please tell how can adding numbers of different types would give proper return types in this method?

Comment: Hmmm... This is tricky. As soon as we make `Complex` class instantiable (i.e. not abstract), every integer will have that field `b`, what I understand you want to avoid. So we have to go with interfaces, but we will end up with `InterfaceName` - `InterfaceNameImpl` antipattern. I will play around and edit my answer.

Comment: Exactly. Looking forward to your answer. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface Numberr {
    public Numberr plus(Numberr n);
    public Numberr minus(Numberr n);
    public Numberr multiply(Numberr n);
    public Numberr sqrt();
    ...

    public Class<? extends Numberr> getType();
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////

public class Integerr implements Numberr {

    protected BigInteger value;

    @Override
    public Numberr plus(Numberr n) {
       if (n instanceof Integerr) {
           return value.add(n.value);
       } else {
           // in case of more broad argument type, use method of that class
           return n.plus(this); 
       }
    }

    ....
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////

public class Rational implements Numberr {

   protected BigInteger numerator;
   protected BigInteger denominator;

   @Override
   public Numberr plus(Numberr n) {
       if (n instance of Integerr) {
           return new Rational(numerator.multiply(n.value), denominator); 
       } else if (n instanceof Rational) {
           return new Rational(numerator.multiply(n.denominator).add(n.numerator.multiply(denominator)), denominator.multiply(n.denominator));
       } else {
           return n.plus(this);
       }
   }

   ....

}
```