# Dynamic Type casting of Objects in Java

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, casting, wrapper

I have a very simple wrapper class which stores object of any class and their type. Now I want to retrieve that object and want to perform some actions on it.

This is a short demo from my code which I am currently using, but it is getting too long

```
Literal a = new Literal(new Complex(12, 0));
Literal b = new Literal(new Matrix(n, m));
Literal c = new Literal(new Variable("x"));
Literal d = new Literal(new Constant("y", 2.25));
Literal e = new Literal(new Real(2.5));

if (a.getType() == Literal.Type.COMPLEX)
{
    Complex w = (Complex)a.getLiteral();
    //Doing something
}
else if (a.getType() == Literal.Type.Matrix)
{
    Matrix w = (Matrix)a.getLiteral();
    //Doing something
}
else if (a.getType() == Literal.Type.Variable)
{
    Variable w = (Variable)a.getLiteral();
    //Doing something
}
else if (a.getType() == Literal.Type.Constant)
{
    Constant w = (Constant)a.getLiteral();
    //Doing something
}
else if (a.getType() == Literal.Type.Real)
{
    Real w = (Real)a.getLiteral();
    //Doing something
}

/* Same goes for all other Objects
* and I need to do this at least in
* 50 different places*/
```

Three solutions came to my mind from which two are not working in this situation

1. Make `Literal` the base class and all others its children, but `Literal` does not have all methods that its children will have and there would be many children.
2. Make `Literal` a generic class, but the types I want to store are mutable so I need copy them and Java does not allow to call any method on generics.
3. This is working, but it increases the probability of errors which are hard to find.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.linear.BlockRealMatrix;

public class Literal<T>
{
    private final Object literal;

    /*
    * public enum Type
    * {
    *   COMPLEX,
    *   VARIABLE,
    *   REAL,
    *   CONSTANT,
    *   MATRIX
    * }
    * private final Type type;
    * */

    public Literal(Complex c)//Complex class is mutable so make copy of passed object
    {
        this.literal = new Complex(c);
        //this.type = Type.COMPLEX;
    }

    public Literal(Real d)//Real is not mutable so no need to make copy
    {
        this.literal = d;
        //this.type = Type.REAL;
    }

    public Literal(BlockRealMatrix realMatrix)//BlockRealMatrix class is mutable so make copy of passed object
    {
        int m = realMatrix.getData().length;
        int n = realMatrix.getData()[0].length;

        BlockRealMatrix mat = new BlockRealMatrix(m, n);

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)mat.setRow(i, realMatrix.getRow(i));
        this.literal = mat;

        //this.type = Type.MATRIX;
    }

    public T get()
    {
        return (T)this.literal;
    }

    /*
    public Literal.Type getType()
    {
        return this.type;
    }
    */

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.literal.toString();
    }
}
```

For the last approach possible error is:

```
package com.kmstudios.evaluator;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Literal<Real> a = new Literal<>(new Complex2(25, 36));//Accidently passed reference of Real instead of Complex
        Literal<Complex2> b = new Literal<>(new Complex2(50, 36));

        Literal<Complex2> c = new Literal<>(a.get().multiply(b.get()));
        System.out.println(c.toString());//Expecting for Complex to print
    }
}

class Real
{
    private final Double d;

    public Real(double d)
    {
        this.d = d;
    }

    public Real multiply(Real other)
    {
        return new Real(this.d * other.d);
    }

    public final double get()
    {
        return this.d;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return Double.toString(this.d);
    }
}

class Complex2 extends Real
{
    private double imaginary;

    public Complex2(double real, double imaginary)
    {
        super(real);
        this.imaginary = imaginary;
    }

    public Complex2 multiply(Complex2 o)
    {
        return new Complex2(this.get() * o.get() - this.imaginary * o.imaginary, this.get() * o.imaginary + this.imaginary * o.get());
    }

    public Complex2 multiply(double other)
    {
        return new Complex2(this.get() * other, this.imaginary * other);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
        builder.append(this.get());

        if (this.imaginary >= 0.0)builder.append("+");
        builder.append(this.imaginary);

        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

I have noticed this one but there may be more errors. Should I reconsider my 
data structures?

I want to know if there is any simple, less error prone, efficient and short way to do this.

Comment: *hard to find errors* post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: where is the problem with the last 4 lines of code?

Comment: @RomanC I have added MCVE

Comment: did any of the answeres helped? if so, you can upvote and accept them!

Comment: @Neuron Your first answer helped me and I up voted that answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the textbook case for the [Visitor pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-visitor).

```
public abstract class Literal<T extends Literal<T>> {
   public abstract void accept(Visitor visitor);
   // other elements
}

public class Variable extends Literal<Variable> {
   public void accept(Visitor visitor) {
      visitor.visit(this);
   }
   // other elements
}
public class Constant extends Literal<Constant> {
   public void accept(Visitor visitor) {
      visitor.visit(this);
   }
   // other elements
}

public interface Visitor {
   public void visit(Variable variable);
   public void visit(Constants variable);
   // ... other types
}

public class DoSomethingVisitor implements Visitor{
   public void visit(Variable variable) {
      // do something with a variable
   }
   public void visit(Constant constant) {
      // do something with a constant
   }
   // other methods.
}
```

Simply put, let the type system help you with method dispatch; no need to reimplement it.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use generics to achieve your goal!
If you need different constructors for the different values, I would suggest using static methods to do the initialisation part and make the constructor private. I seem to work in your case..

```
public class Literal<T>
{
    private final T literal;

    private Literal(T literal) {
        this.literal = literal;
    }

    public T get(){
        return literal;
    }

    public static Literal<Complex> createComplexLiteral(Complex complex){
        return new Literal<>(complex);
    }

    public static Literal<BlockRealMatrix> createBlockRealMatrixLiteral(BlockRealMatrix complex){
        int m = realMatrix.getData().length;
        int n = realMatrix.getData()[0].length;

        BlockRealMatrix mat = new BlockRealMatrix(m, n);

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)mat.setRow(i, realMatrix.getRow(i));
        return new Literal<>(mat);
    }

    // all the other create methods
}
```

You could now call:

```
Literal<Complex> complexLiteral = Literal.createComplexLiteral(someComplex);
```

On a side note.. Try using a switch case for your enums. They are much faster and arguably less ugly than a hundred `if elseif` blocks And always capitalize names of enums, since they are basically final constants. [This tutorial site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) by oracle itself suggests this naming convention:

```
switch(a.getType()){
    case COMPLEX:
        Complex w = (Complex)a.getLiteral();
        //Doing something
        break;
    case MATRIX:
        Matrix w = (Matrix)a.getLiteral();
        //Doing something
        break;
    case VARIABLE:
        Variable w = (Variable)a.getLiteral();
        //Doing something
        break;
    // other types..
    default: // always include a default for your switch case, just in case..
        throw new RuntimeException("unknown type "+a.getType());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this as a new answer, since you updated your question and I can provide an alternative explanation as to why your code example doesn't produce what you had in mind (while the old post is still valid):
Your two classes `Real` and `Complex2` have the inheritance the wrong way round. Consider the following example:

```
Complex2 complex = new Complex2(2, 3);
Real real = new Real(3);
Real result = real.multiply(complex); // returns an object equal to new Real(6)
Real result = complex.multiply(real); // and even this code returns the same result
```

So why is the inheritance wrong? We know that the real numbers are a subset of the complex numbers. So every real number is always also a complex number, not the other way round! Make `Real` extend `Complex2` and create a constructor:

```
public Real(double number){
    super(number, 0);
}
```

Comment: I have heard that child shoudl be super-set and parent should be subset

Comment: when `X` inherits `Y` always ask yourself: is every `X` a `Y`? The classes `Complex2` and `Real` fails this test, because: Is every complex number a real number? No! You can find a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963147/inheritance-hierarchy-for-number-system-classes

Comment: And please consider upvoting any answers which were helpful